# Dump all variables excluding the global ones

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I want to dump all variables defined in the local scope. I checked `get_defined_vars()` but it also including variables in global scope.

Is there some built in PHP function that allows you to dump variables in local scope?

Answer (score 4):

`get_defined_vars` works within the scope that it is called. If you call it within the global scope it will get every variable in that scope. Call in within a function and it would get all the variables within that functions scope.

It's all relative so depending on where you call it you will get different results. If you only want the local variables then call the function in the local scope. If you are getting the global variables then you are calling the function in the global not local scope.

Comment: I am using it in an included file without any function and it is still showing global variables

Comment: If you arent using it within a function/closure or class method then it is being used in the global scope which is why it returns all global vars

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking.

Comment: If you dont want to show all of the global variables when using this function then you will have to loop through all returned keys and remove the ones you dont want. See @m79lkm's answer for that.

Comment: Couldn't you do foreach(get_defined_vars() as $i => $val) in conjunction with `if( array_key_exists($i, $GLOBALS)) continue;`?

Answer (score 1):

`get_defined_vars()` returns variables visible in a scope where it was called-

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, get_defined_vars() will return all variables within the scope it was called. One option is to filter what it returns based on convention:

```
$arr = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/_[A-Z]+/', $key)) unset($arr[$key]);
}
print_r($arr);
```